# How could I create new objects in an object with a function?

Tags: javascript

I need to create new objects in an object with a function. It should work this way: I need to collect some data into a big object that consists of some smaller objects that I should create using a function.
It works this way: a user gets a created by my function object, fills it and then this object is pushed to the big object. The problem is I don't totally understand how to create a new object every time because my code just changes data in one object. The creation of the new function should happens only when it's required by a user.

My code:

```
let ger_tasks = {}
let name = 1;
let descr = 2;
let timing = 3;


function newTask(name,descr,timing) {
    this.name = name;
     this.descr = descr;
     this.timing = timing;
        name = {
        description:descr,
        timings:timing,
       
    }
    ger_tasks.name = name;
    }
    newTask('a','b','c')
    newTask('0','1','2')
    console.log(ger_tasks)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry you said ```a user gets a``` and missed the word . i just run your code . do you mean you want to append the object  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet of my try on it  :

```
let ger_task = {}
let name = 1;
let descr = 2;
let timing = 3;


function newTask(name,descr,timing) {
    this.name = name;
    this.descr = descr;
    this.timing = timing;
    content = {
        description:this.descr,
        timings:this.timing,
       
    }
    ger_task[name] = this.content;
    }
    newTask('a','b','c')
    newTask('0','1','2')
    console.log(ger_task)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **square bracket notation**:

```js
ger_tasks[name] = /*varname*/;
```

Also, don't call your variable `name` - instead something else so that the parameter is not overwritten